# JavaScript-How to make Html Table editable

Tags: javascript

I have a function of creating table from a .csv file using JavaScript. I want to make the last column of the table editable. Part of that function where table is being generated is

```
for (var i = 0; i < CSVLines.length; i++) {
    OutputTableRows += "<tr>";
    var CSVValues = CSVLines[i].split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < CSVValues.length; j++) {
        OutputTableRows += "<td>" + "<p>" + CSVValues[j] + "<p>" + "</td>";
    }
    OutputTableRows += "</tr>";
}
```

I have tried

```
OutputTableRows += "<td>" + "<p contenteditable="true">" + CSVValues[j] + "<p>" + "</td>";
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should say in your inner loop:-

```
if(j == CSVValues.length-1){
     tableRow = '<td><input type="text" value="VALUE"/></td>';
     tableRow = tableRow.replace('VALUE',CSVValues[j]);
     OutputTableRows += tableRow;
}
else{
   OutputTableRows += "<td>" + "<p>" + CSVValues[j] + "<p>" + "</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, at first glance:

```
OutputTableRows += "<td>" + "<p" + (j === (CSVValues.length - 1) ? " contentEditable" : "") + ">" + CSVValues[j] + "</p>" +"</td>";
```

The relevant part, of course, is:

```
"<p" + (j === (CSVValues.length - 1) ? " contentEditable" : "") + ">"
```

If `j` is equal to the length of `CSVValues` minus 1, then it's reasonable to assume that this must be the last iteration of that `for` loop, and therefore this is the row that should have the `contentEditable` attribute, otherwise it should not (and must be an earlier iteration of the loop).

Also, note the changed `</p>` (from your original `<p>`), which closes the already-open `<p>`, as opposed to creating a new, sibling, paragraph element.

References:

- [Conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`contentEditable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am working on a Windows 8.1 application using VS 2013 following exception occurred when I used your answer.

**0x800c001c - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content. A script attempted to inject dynamic content or elements previously modified dynamically that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.**